# how to smoothly set layout height

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an ImageView inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout and the ImageView takes up the whole screen with some info at the bottom. When user clicks on the ImageView i'd like the height of the CollapsingToolBarLayout to become `150dp`. How do I set the height of the CollapsingToolBarLayout to have a smooth animation to be set to height of `150dp`. I'd like the height to smoothly and slowly get to `150dp` not quick, to have a nice animation. 
How can i achieve this?

activity_scrolling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.myapplication.foodapp.ScrollingActivity"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chipotle_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:src="@mipmap/food1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chipotle Chicken Fajitas"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/first_food_title"/>

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="16 ingredients | 284 Calories | 1 hour"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/spec_text"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/arrow"
                    android:id="@id/back_Arrow"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />




            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>




    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- ** CONTENT SCROLLING LAYOUT ** -->
<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling">

</include>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with ValueAnimator.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewToIncreaseHeight.getMeasuredHeight(), finalValue);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewGroup.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = val;
        viewGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});
anim.start();
```